# Configure php mail() on Windows/IIS

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, php

I have a Windows Server 2003 / IIS web server running various application servers, and ended up begrudgingly adding PHP into the mix. I know Win/IIS isn't the ideal environment for PHP, but it's what I've got and I need to make it work.

From `phpinfo()`:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:   C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File:           C:\php\php.ini
```

From `C:\php\php.ini`:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
;sendmail_path =

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =
```

Lastly, I have IIS setup to run an SMTP relay that allows connection and relay, but only from localhost.

But when I try something that uses `mail()`, I get this error:

```
The e-mail could not be sent.
Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try sending an email using telnet and post the exchange here.

Comment: Did you bounce IIS after configuring PHP via the ini?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SMTP server configured on localhost ? If no then 2 ways:
1. Use your ISP's SMTP instead localhost
2. Configure your SMTP server on your localhost. There is more options:
a) bundled with win2k3 (appwiz.cpl)
b) use 3rd party smtp server

Comment: "Lastly, I have IIS setup to run an SMTP relay that allows connection and relay, but only from localhost."

Comment: You can configure IIS SMTP server for all outbound mails in easy way. mark my previous answer ;)